# How to create a animation like web what´s app attach menu?

Tags: css, css-animations, dropdown

I´ve tried to see what css property web whats app attach menu is making the animation but didn´t find it

[image]

I´ve tried using

```
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
```

But didn´t work also

## solved

by using this css class

```
.transform-scale-animate{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
}
```

related to this html

```
 <div tabindex="-1" class="_1txFK transform-scale-animate" style="transform-origin: left top 0px;">
   <ul class="_3s1D4">
    <li tabindex="-1" class="_10anr vidHz _3asN5" data-animate-dropdown-item="true">
     <button class="btn-attach" id="btn-attach-photo">
```

js

```
btnAttach.on('click', e => {
 e.stopPropagation()
 if (this.el.menuAttach.classList.contains('open')) {
  this.closeMenuAttach()
 } else {
  this.el.menuAttach.addClass('open')
  document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenuAttach.bind(this))
     this.el.menuAttach.children[0].style.transform = 'scale(1)' 
 }
```

})

using the transform:scale(0) to hide the menu and scale(1) to show the menu
works

```
if (!menuDropDown.style.transform ||
        menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(0)') {
        menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(1)'
    } else  {
        menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(0)'
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where's your HTML? Where's the rest of your CSS? The question as it stands is far too broad to help. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @disinfor... I´ve was able to solve using `transform:scale` css property...

Comment: While that's great that you solved your problem, the code you provided as your solution isn't complete - a future visitor would not benefit from this.

Comment: @disinfor... I´ll try to make a code pen working example

Comment: @disinfor.. I´ve made it a code pen example... however I don´t have too much experience with codepen, so the javascript and the css appear to not work properly... as it is working 'normally' in the browser.... the link for the code pen is (https://codepen.io/adriel-werlich/pen/oNvYvZP)
For some reason the javascript is not changing the transform attribute of the dropdown menu `if (!menuDropDown.style.transform ||
  menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(0)') {
  menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(1)'
 } else  {
  menuDropDown.style.transform === 'scale(0)'
 }`

Comment: I´ve found this example also (https://www.codeply.com/go/3i8LzYVfMF) using only css... seems like a even simpler solution...

Answer (score 1):

To add to what you already figured out yourself, you can use transition-delay to have the menu be completely in CSS:

```css
/* make "buttons" round */
label[for="menu"], .menu-items a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* actual menu buttons - padding, animation, transforms */
.menu-items a {
  margin-top: 4px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transform-origin: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* ideally use SCSS/LESS/etc. instead of coding these by hand */
.menu-items a:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: 0.1s; }
.menu-items a:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.2s; }
.menu-items a:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.3s; }
.menu-items a:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.4s; }

/* closed/open styles for animations: */
#menu:not(:checked) ~ .menu-items a {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5px) scale(0.5);
}
#menu:checked ~ .menu-items a {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" hidden id="menu" name="menu">
<label for="menu">✨</label>
<div class="menu-items">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```